# Reference cell formatting in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatting

Let's say I have a cell with a specific formatting. Is there a way to assign that formatting to another cells so that when the original cell formatting is changed all the dependent cell formatting is also changed?

If there is no appropriate answer for this, then I will simplify my question with the following: imagine that both the content and formatting of the dependent cells should 100% be the same as the original cell. So when I change something (value, format) in the original cell, then it is being propagated to all the dependent cells. Is at least this possible to do?

Comment: possible only with script

Comment: @player0, sounds good. How can we do that?

Comment: Look at class range getNumberFormat() and setNumberFormat().  There are other commands and copyTo() can copy formatting.

Comment: formatting changes isn't captured by any trigger (e.g onchange, onedit, etc) so you need an alternative to make it work. either a button, or forcing the reference cell to trigger the script which is what the answer posted below does. copyTo is your friend here. (I assume format means something like bold, text font, color, italicize, etc.) it should also work on data formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use triggers like `onEdit` but the catch is that it can't capture events like for example changing formats. It only is triggered by value changes. So see this script below:

#### Script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var referenceCell = 'A1';
  var dependentCells = ['C1', 'D1'];

  // if cell edited is Sheet1!A1
  if(sheet.getSheetName() == 'Sheet1' && range.getA1Notation() == referenceCell) {
    dependentCells.forEach(dependentCell => {
      sheet.getRange(referenceCell).copyTo(sheet.getRange(dependentCell), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
    });
  }
}
```

#### Behavior:

- Dependent cells' (C1 and D1) formats will only be updated when A1 value is updated.
- After triggering the script, you can always revert the value of the reference cell (A1).

#### Output:

[image: output]

This is only an alternative to your first question as format changes can't trigger functions.

For your second one, if you also want to copy including the values, then use `PASTE_NORMAL` instead of `PASTE_FORMAT`.

See other copy paste type values on the reference below.

#### References:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/copy-paste-type